# MongoDB join data inside an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have document like this in a collection called **diagnoses** :

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("582d43d18ec3f432f3260682"),
        "patientid" : ObjectId("582aacff3894c3afd7ad4677"),
        "doctorid" : ObjectId("582a80c93894c3afd7ad4675"),
        "medicalcondition" : "high fever, cough, runny nose.",
        "diagnosis" : "Viral Flu",
        "addmissiondate" : "2016-01-12",
        "dischargedate" : "2016-01-16",
        "bhtno" : "125",
        "prescription" : [ 
            {
                "drug" : ObjectId("58345e0e996d340bd8126149"),
                "instructions" : "Take 2 daily, after meals."
            }, 
            {
                "drug" : ObjectId("5836bc0b291918eb42966320"),
                "instructions" : "Take 1 daily, after meals."
            }
        ]
    }
```

The **drug** id inside the prescription object array is from a separate collection called **drugs**, see sample document below :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58345e0e996d340bd8126149"),
    "genericname" : "Paracetamol Tab 500mg",
    "type" : "X",
    "isbrand" : false
}
```

I am trying to create a mongodb query using the native node.js driver to get a result like this:

```
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("582d43d18ec3f432f3260682"),
                "patientid" : ObjectId("582aacff3894c3afd7ad4677"),
                "doctorid" : ObjectId("582a80c93894c3afd7ad4675"),
                "medicalcondition" : "high fever, cough, runny nose.",
                "diagnosis" : "Viral Flu",
                "addmissiondate" : "2016-01-12",
                "dischargedate" : "2016-01-16",
                "bhtno" : "125",
                "prescription" : [ 
                    {
                        "drug" : 
                        {
                          "_id" : ObjectId("58345e0e996d340bd8126149"),
                          "genericname" : "Paracetamol Tab 500mg",
                          "type" : "X",
                          "isbrand" : false
                        },
                        "instructions" : "Take 2 daily, after meals."
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            }
```

Any advice on how to approach a similar result like this is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Using MongoDB 3.4.4 and newer**

With the aggregation framework, the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operators supports arrays

```
db.diagnoses.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": { 
        "prescription": { "$ifNull" : [ "$prescription", [ ] ] }    
    } },
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "drugs",
        "localField": "prescription.drug",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "drugs"
    } },
    { "$addFields": {
        "prescription": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$prescription",
                "in": {
                    "$mergeObjects": [
                        "$$this",
                        { "drug": {
                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                                "$drugs",
                                { 
                                    "$indexOfArray": [
                                        "$drugs._id",
                                        "$$this.drug"
                                    ] 
                                }
                            ]
                        } }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    } },
    { "$project": { "drugs": 0 } }
])
```

**For older MongoDB versions:**

You can create a pipeline that first flattens the `prescription` array using the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator and a **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** subsequent pipeline step to do a "left outer join" on the "drugs" collection. Apply another **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operation on the created array from the "joined" field. **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** the previously flattened documents from the first pipeline where there **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator outputs a document for each element in the prescription array.

Assembling the above pipeline, run the following aggregate operation:

```
db.diagnoses.aggregate([
    { 
        "$project": {               
            "patientid": 1,
            "doctorid": 1,
            "medicalcondition": 1,
            "diagnosis": 1,
            "addmissiondate": 1,
            "dischargedate": 1,
            "bhtno": 1,
            "prescription": { "$ifNull" : [ "$prescription", [ ] ] } 
        }
    },
    {
       "$unwind": {
           "path": "$prescription",
           "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    },      
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "drugs",
            "localField": "prescription.drug",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "prescription.drug"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$prescription.drug" },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "patientid" : { "$first": "$patientid" },
            "doctorid" : { "$first": "$doctorid" },
            "medicalcondition" : { "$first": "$medicalcondition" },
            "diagnosis" : { "$first": "$diagnosis" },
            "addmissiondate" : { "$first": "$addmissiondate" },
            "dischargedate" : { "$first": "$dischargedate" },
            "bhtno" : { "$first": "$bhtno" },
            "prescription" : { "$push": "$prescription" }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582d43d18ec3f432f3260682"),
    "patientid" : ObjectId("582aacff3894c3afd7ad4677"),
    "doctorid" : ObjectId("582a80c93894c3afd7ad4675"),
    "medicalcondition" : "high fever, cough, runny nose.",
    "diagnosis" : "Viral Flu",
    "addmissiondate" : "2016-01-12",
    "dischargedate" : "2016-01-16",
    "bhtno" : "125",
    "prescription" : [ 
        {
            "drug" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("58345e0e996d340bd8126149"),
                "genericname" : "Paracetamol Tab 500mg",
                "type" : "X",
                "isbrand" : false
            },
            "instructions" : "Take 2 daily, after meals."
        }, 
        {
            "drug" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5836bc0b291918eb42966320"),
                "genericname" : "Paracetamol Tab 100mg",
                "type" : "Y",
                "isbrand" : false
            },
            "instructions" : "Take 1 daily, after meals."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I came across a small issue with this query, in case there is no prescription data meaning the array is not there in the document, the query wont return anything, is there some way to make this work like a left join?

Comment: @VindulaFernando Updated answer with an approach. Please check.

Comment: Still getting the same result my diagnosis document looks like this in that scenario 
` {
        "_id" : ObjectId("582d43d18ec3f432f3260682"),
        "patientid" : ObjectId("582aacff3894c3afd7ad4677"),
        "doctorid" : ObjectId("582a80c93894c3afd7ad4675"),
        "medicalcondition" : "high fever, cough, runny nose.",
        "diagnosis" : "Viral Flu",
        "addmissiondate" : "2016-01-12",
        "dischargedate" : "2016-01-16",
        "bhtno" : "125"
}`

Comment: any reason that you can see ?

Comment: You could use the `$ifNull` operator to project an empty array as placeholder if the `prescription` field does not exist, as in the updated answer.

Comment: I have followed this answer for 3.4.4+ and applied it to my own collections/fields.  And I'm finding that my equivalent of the "prescription" array only contains the 'drug' object after the $lookup (prescription.drug) - the original contents of the array (i.e. the 'instructions' string) are gone. I think there is a modification required to this answer to produce the sample output as shown ?

Comment: How can I hide some of the fields in the prescription array and also in the drug object ?

Answer (score 1):

**In MongoDB 3.6 or later versions**

It seems that
`$lookup` will overwrite the original array instead of merging it.
A working solution (a workaround, if you prefer) is to create a different field,
and then merge two fields, as shown below:

```
db.diagnoses.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "drugs",
        "localField": "prescription.drug",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "prescription_drug_info"
    } },
    { "$addFields": {
        "merged_drug_info": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$prescription",
                "in": {
                    "$mergeObjects": [
                        "$$this",
                        { "$arrayElemAt": [
                            "$prescription_drug_info._id",
                            "$$this._id"
                        ] }
                    ] 
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

This would add two more fields and the name of the desired field
will be `merged_drug_info`. We can then add `$project` stage to filter
out excessive fields and `$set` stage to rename the field:

```
...
{ "$set": { "prescription": "$merged_drug_info" } },
{ "$project": { "prescription_drug_info": 0, "merged_drug_info": 0 } }
...
```