# mongodb populate with aggreagation pipeline via objectid (Fill object data in array using objectid)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I tried using the aggregation lookup but it didn't work, when I try to replace the objectId or at least replace it the old data get overridden and I loose the the `"users"` array.
I would like to get some help.

This is my current DB.

```
db={
  "Persons": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62d7b53009b0fd96353c043f"
      },
      "Name": "Alice",
      "petName": "Alice jr"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62e7cc0e264d240455f66110"
      },
      "Name": "Bob",
      "Age": 27
    }
  ],
  "Accounts": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62e788b5264d240455f6610c"
      },
      "banned": [],
      "active": [
        {
          "users": [
            {
              "first": "BobRules",
              "second": "BobTheThird"
            }
          ],
          "person": {
            "$oid": "62e7cc0e264d240455f66110"
          },
        },
        {
          "users": [
            {
              "first": "AliceRules",
              "second": "AliceTheSecond"
            },
            {
              "first": "SecretAlice",
              "second": "AliceAndEve"
            }
          ],
          "person": {
            "$oid": "62d7b53009b0fd96353c043f"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the output I would like to get.

```
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62e788b5264d240455f6610c"
      },
      "banned": [],
      "active": [
        {
          "users": [
            {
              "first": "BobRules",
              "second": "BobTheThird"
            }
          ],
          "person": {
            "$oid": "62e7cc0e264d240455f66110",
            "Name": "Bob",
            "Age": 27
          },
        },
        {
          "users": [
            {
              "first": "AliceRules",
              "second": "AliceTheSecond"
            },
            {
              "first": "SecretAlice",
              "second": "AliceAndEve"
            }
          ],
          "person": {
            "$oid": "62d7b53009b0fd96353c043f",
            "Name": "Alice",
            "petName": "Alice jr"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to get the wanted result, thanks to  the answer in this question: [MongoDB join data inside an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992111/mongodb-join-data-inside-an-array-of-objects)

The aggregation had to be:

```
[{
    $addFields: {
        active: {
            $ifNull: [
                '$active',
                []
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'Persons',
        localField: 'active.person',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'persons'
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        active: {
            $map: {
                input: '$active',
                'in': {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                        '$$this',
                        {
                            person: {
                                $arrayElemAt: [
                                    '$persons',
                                    {
                                        $indexOfArray: [
                                            '$persons._id',
                                            '$$this.person'
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        persons: 0
    }
}]
```